# No Service worker files ngsw.json / ngsw-worker.json generated when running build --prod. Angular 5

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

Using angular 5.1.2 Angular-cli 1.6.3

all files are pretty vanilla. dist folder is created

My ngsw-config.json

```
{
"index": "/index.html",
"assetGroups": [
    {
        "name": "app",
        "installMode": "prefetch",
        "resources": {
            "files": [
                "/favicon.ico",
                "/index.html"
            ],
            "versionedFiles": [
                "/*.bundle.css",
                "/*.bundle.js",
                "/*.chunk.js"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "assets",
        "installMode": "lazy",
        "updateMode": "prefetch",
        "resources": {
            "files": [
                "/assets/**"
            ]
        }
    }]
```

}

my app.module.ts uses

```
  ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
```

am using vanilla environment.ts and environment.prod.ts

main.ts

```
import './polyfills.ts';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import {AppModule} from './app/app.module';
import {environment} from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.then(() => {
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('ngsw-worker.js');
}

})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Not sure what else to check

Comment: Same for me. I don't have these files in any build output and thus get "NotFound" from http-server when trying to retrieve them. But the strange thing is that the hosted application on Azure has the service-worker and registers it as expected. Is it maybe a known Angular-Cli problem of any version? Or did I forget to set any flag on the build scripts? I also have the ServiceWorkerModule.register call and the serviceWorker=true flag set.

Answer (score 23):

Do you add `serviceWorker` property to `apps` first entry in `.angular-cli.json`? If not, angular-cli not built it.

```
"apps": [
  {
    ...
    "serviceWorker": true
  }
}
```

---

***EDIT*** As of December 2018, **.angular-cli.json** is now **angular.json**, and the format for the serviceWorker is now:

```
{
    ...
    "projects": {
         "my-project-name": {
             "architect": {
                 "build": {
                     "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                           "serviceWorker": true
                        }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
    }
```

You'll need to specify serviceWorker: true for every configuration where you want the service worker.

Comment: I have tried the above but it has not helped.., see angular-cli below:

       {
      "project": {
        "name": "ThatApp"
      },
      "apps": [
        {
            "serviceWorker": true,
            "root": "src",
         ......
        "component": {
          "spec": true,
          "inlineStyle": false,
          "inlineTemplate": false
        }
      } 
    }

Comment: I've updated your answer for the newest Angular (v7 at the time of this writing).

Comment: Thanks, this is the problem i was facing because i have different configuration for different environment, it is only configured for Production and i need to set it manually to my other configurations

```
"serviceWorker": true,
"ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. It turns out I was using a old package

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.6"
```

This should be

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
```

after this, the service worker is copied

Also make sure to be using latest Angular 7 and lateset Angular CLI

Answer (score 5):

After a long search, we found out that the missing --prod flag in our build makes the problem. Exactly this one produces the service-worker files and no additional build flag is able to do it (same with uglifying and the uglifyer was the reason why we had exchanged the --build flag against --env=build earlier). More information about what happens on the --build flag to be found here: [Angular 2 with CLI - build for production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066267/angular-2-with-cli-build-for-production).

Answer (score -3):

It appears my app.module.ts was missing a space

I had:
  environment.production ? ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js') :[]

changed to:
  environment.production ? ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js') : []

Comment: Extra whitespace doesn't matter in JavaScript.